# Convert 0-100 (decimal percent) to 8 bits

Tags: python

I am often converting 0-100 decimal percentages to 8-bit numbers for reading values and controlling things. I've always used simple ratio math:

```
def percent_to_byte(percent):
    if (percent >=0) and (percent <=100):
        return bytes([int(percent * 2.55)])
```

and accepted the inaccuracies:

```
import sys

for x in range(256):
    y = x/2.56
    print(x, y, int.from_bytes(percent_to_byte(y),sys.byteorder))
```

Output:

```
0, 0.0, 0
1, 0.390625, 0
...
127, 49.609375, 126
...
255, 99.609375, 254
```

In each line above, the first and last values should be the same.

In Python 3+, given the set of real numbers between 0 and 100 inclusive {x | 0 ≤ x ≤ 100, x in R}, return the 8-bit binary equivalent.

Comment: Please be more specific with the issue you're facing, for example you already have a simple code, why doesn't that work for your purposes. What exactly do you want to improve?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing out that I never asked a question.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related question. If you're asking how to improve your working code, consider: [CodeReview SO](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Or b: I'm pretty rusty & green. Could you write an answer and spell out the {bytes} solution?

Comment: @0stone0, I see your point, but my code *appears* to return inaccuracies. Seems OK to leave  as programming vs. code review. Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to fix those inaccuracies, please [edit] the question and add a [mre]. Some examples might help!

Comment: To be very specific: you expect the first and last values in each line of output to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the calculation in `percent_to_byte` to

```
        return bytes([int((percent * 255)/100)])
```

and change to scaling in the loop to

```
    y = x/2.55
```

Then this loop does not print any discrepancies:

```
for x in range(256): 
    y = x/2.55 
    z = int.from_bytes(percent_to_byte(y),sys.byteorder) 
    if z != x: 
        print(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove redundant parts of your code:

From

```
def percent_to_byte(percent):
    if (percent >=0) and (percent <=100):
        return bytes([int(percent * 2.55)])
```

To

```
def percent_to_byte(percent):
    if 100 >= percent >= 0:
        return bytes([int(percent * 2.55)])
```